# Order of the group generated by two matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to find the order of the group generated by the matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&i\\-i&0\end{pmatrix}$$
under multiplication.

$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&i\\-i&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}$
 and $\begin{pmatrix}-i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}^4=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ so $4$ is the order? am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This group contains, e.g., $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$.

**Addendum:** Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&i\\-i&0\end{pmatrix}$. We have $A^4=I, B^2=I, AB=BA$. Hence the group generated by them is $\langle A\rangle \times \langle B \rangle $ and has order 8.

Comment: I think it will be infinite order?

Comment: No. I will answer in one hour.

Comment: @miosaki I added my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Show that the group consist precisely of the matrices of the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix}0&u\\-u&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad\text{or}\qquad\begin{pmatrix}u&0\\0&u\end{pmatrix}$$
with $u\in\{1,-1,i,-i\}$. Then count.

Comment: From this, you should also be able to conjecture on what group this is isomorphic to.